# Enlarging date range of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have a dataframe generated by this code:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame([['2018-02-05', '2018-02-11', '2018-02-12'], [77, 77, 77]]).transpose()
df_.set_index(keys = 0, inplace = True)
```

I would like to create a dataframe based on `df_` that spans the following daterange

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2018-02-01')
end_date = start_date + pd.DateOffset(months=1) - pd.DateOffset(days=14)
index_ = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date)
```

The missing values in df_ should be filled with zeros. Is their a quick way to do this, w/o converting `index_` into a dataframe and then applying something like `pd.merge` or `pd.concat`?

Thanks and please let me know in case you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

I think need convert index [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_datetime.html) and then use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) if all values in `index_` and original `df.index` are unique:

```
df_.index = pd.to_datetime(df_.index)
df = df_.reindex(index_, fill_value=0)
print (df)
             1
2018-02-01   0
2018-02-02   0
2018-02-03   0
2018-02-04   0
2018-02-05  77
2018-02-06   0
2018-02-07   0
2018-02-08   0
2018-02-09   0
2018-02-10   0
2018-02-11  77
2018-02-12  77
2018-02-13   0
2018-02-14   0
2018-02-15   0
```